# CNAME redirect with javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, cname

I have one server, `server.domain.local` that hosts 3+ web applications. I have aliases for all of these apps so I can browse to:

`http://alias1/alias1website.htm`
`http://alias2:`**`alias2port`**`/alias2website.htm`
`http://alias3:`**`alias3port`**`/alias3website.htm`

I need to be able to modify the `iisstart.htm` with javascript so that depending on the alias a user puts in the browser, it redirects to a site and port w/ address.

Ex: `http://alias3` should redirect to `http://alias3:`**`alias3port`**`/alias3website.htm`.

I know this is possible, I have done it before, I just cannot for the life of me remeber the code.

Comment: [CNAMEs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME) are used to create alises at the DNS level; any redirect you could do in JavaScript wouldn't be directly related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with an `if` statement.

```
if(window.location.hostname == 'alias3'){
    window.location = 'ht55tp://alias3:alias3port/alias3website.htm';
}
```